# React native transparent text

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to achieve the following effect
[button with transparent text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEodl.png)

my code fragment:

```
                     <ImageBackground source={require('...')}>
                        <View style={[styles.buttonView, {flex: 2, backgroundColor: 'white'}]}>
                            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.6}>
                                <View style={{paddingTop: 15, paddingBottom: 15}}>
                                    <Text style={[styles.textItem, {fontWeight: "bold", color: 'transparent'}]}>
                                        Kobieta
                                    </Text>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                      </ImageBackground>
```

But currently text in the button has white color.

Comment: It is unclear by your example what you mean by "transparent text". Could you give more examples please? Do you want completely "clear" text that is exactly the color of the background, or do you want partially transparent text that is a blend of the text color and the background color? or something else?

Comment: To confirm, you're needing to achieve a "masking" effect, where the text is transparent against the background to reveal the gradient behind the button?

Comment: I uploaded example how it should look.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting backgroundColor:'transparent' instead of the color.

Comment: I am not sure if backgroundColor is aplicable for <Text>